# Reading files from S3 to kafka topic

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

I have a situation wherein all the event data is getting stored in an s3 bucket and I need to fetch that from S3 to Kafka topic on ec2. I am using CamelAWSS3Connector and am facing issues of the connector not working.
Following is the error I am facing

```
[2023-01-06 10:11:21,048] ERROR Failed to create job for config/s3_connect.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:107)
[2023-01-06 10:11:21,053] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:117)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jctools/queues/MessagePassingQueue$Supplier
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:99)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jctools/queues/MessagePassingQueue$Supplier
```

I was expecting the publisher to push msg to topic from s3 to kafka

Following is my properties files

```
name=CamelAwss3SourceConnector
connector.class=org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.aws2s3.CamelAws2s3SourceConnector
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
camel.source.maxPollDuration=10000 
topics=mytopic
camel.component.aws-s3.access-key=XXXXXXXX
camel.component.aws-s3.region=ap-south-1
camel.source.path.bucketNameOrArn=poc-s3-kafkatopic
camel.source.endpoint.autocloseBody=true
camel.source.endpoint.deleteAfterRead=true
```

After using export command and adding jars location before calling the publisher following is the error

```
[2023-01-11 06:43:05,528] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:117) java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/kafkaconnector/CamelSourceConnectorConfig
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:99)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:114) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/kafkaconnector/CamelSourceConnectorConfig
```

Comment: What is the camel-kafka-connector version you're using?

Comment: Where did you download your Camel Connector from? Please [edit] to include your `connect-standalone.properties`... Seems like you're missing some JARs in your `plugin.path`

Comment: https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/3.18.x/reference/index.html  this is the place from where I have downloaded the source connector @OneCricketeer

Comment: I am not sure of the version of the camel-kafka-connector @Oscerd

Comment: I have pasted my properties file above @OneCricketeer

Comment: Thanks. The version is in the url or the jar you've downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added `plugin.path=/path/to/extracted-camel-connector` to the `connect-standalone.properties` file.

And if that doesn't work, you'll need to export `CLASSPATH` environment variable to include the jar files in that path.

Comment: Tried all of this still not working

Comment: Do you still get `NoClassDefFoundError`, or something else? I don't have an S3 bucket to test your configs with

Comment: Yes, same no class found error